# How can I checkout a branch in a new gitg?

Tags: gitg

In the older GNOME2 gitg interface it was easily possible to checkout a branch by clicking on it with a right mouse button. How can I checkout a branch in the new GNOME3 interface? Right-click now only allows to Rename, Remove, Copy Name, and set a Mainline.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't.

**Gitg** is a git repository viewer which also lets you merge and commit. But fetch, branch are apparently not implemented.